# Getting output displayed for a each single line Python IDLE

Tags: spyder, python-idle

I am new to Python, and I am currently doing an online course on "Automate the Boring stuff with Python" on udemy.com. I have a very basic problem, and that's as you can see in the highlighted portion of the following screenshot:
[Displayed output in blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftUSu.png)

The author of this online course just presses some keyboard key on a particular line and gets the out the output displayed in blue for haRegex.search. But in my case when I press enter I don't see such an output upon pressing the enter key. Previously I used to use Spyder, and get single line execution by simply pressing F9, and the the console showed the output as OUT:abcd. But, now since updating to Spyder 4.1.3, Spyder won't display the output in the console window for a single line upon pressing F9. So, I decided using Python IDLE as suggested in the course, so can someone please guide as to how can execute a single line and get its output displayed in blue as shown in the screenshot? My code is as follows:

```
>>> haRegex = re.compile(r'(Ha)(3)')
>>> haRegex.search('He said "HaHaHa"')
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You finish entering a line by hitting the Enter key.  If the code is complete, it executes.  If not, you must enter more lines.  If you enter a compound statement, with a header ending with ':', you must enter an extra blank line.

If the result of execution is 'None', nothing is printed and '>>>' is printed.  Otherwise the result is printed.  In your example, haRegex does not match the search string, even if you think it does, so nothing is printed.  Use re 'Ha' and there will be a match.  In 3.9, the result is `<re.Match object; span=(9, 11), match='Ha'>`.

The Shell output color is set by the current syntax highlight theme.  For black on white normal text, it is currently blue, as in the screenshot.  To check,  Select `Options` => `Configure IDLE`, then the `Highlights` tab, and look at the sample.  If you are not satisfied with any built-in theme, make a custom theme you like better.

Comment: Can you please explain the syntax for re 'Ha' in order to get a match? And also, how come the author is getting a match then, as shown in the yellow highlighted portion?

Comment: The re 'Ha' simply matches any occurrence of 'Ha' in the target text.  The yellow-highlighted re contains '{3}' (note curely braces), which matches 3 occurrences of the previous item, 'Ha'.  The mis-copied '(3)' (smooth parentheses) matches '3', which is not in the target text.